# table.keyfield=table.field2 gives (0x80131904): An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: vb.net

First post

I have been struggling with this for hours today and have not been able to find much on the web.

I have a vb.net program that runs a query string that is read from a configuration file that needs to be configurable (not the problem). The queries work fine with the below code so long as there is no clause '=' that isn't a boolean. (ex where table1.fieldkey=table2.key)

I get the error: 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'key'.

Code:

```
Public Sub DoQuery()
Dim cn As New SqlConnection(), cmd As New SqlCommand(), schemaTable As DataTable, myReader As SqlDataReader, myadapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim myField As DataRow, myProperty As DataColumn
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    Dim queryOutput As New DataTable
    'Open a connection to the SQL Server
    cn.ConnectionString = connectString
    cn.Open()
    'Retrieve records
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = query
    Try
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteLog("An error occured. Check the SQL query" & Chr(13) & ex.ToString)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
Using cn
        myadapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        myadapter.Fill(queryOutput)
    End Using
cn.Close()
end sub
```

Query:

```
select ta.[Key], ta.Name, ta.currentstationkey as Station, te.Discriminator as Type, ta.Material, ta.MaterialDescription 
from TrackedAssets as ta, TrackingEvents as te 
where ta.[key]=te.assetkey
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems that the connection string can't handle the where field=field.

Comment: What line causes the exception?

Comment: Funny coding but [most likely] error is not generated in it. Use this as example how to form your code to execute data adapters. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30179870/1704458

Comment: Exception happens here
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Comment: I have modified the code to use "using" statements like @T.S. explained, but the same exception occurs at myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

Comment: [answer] There was a problem with the way I was reading the query input into a string. I "string.split()" the configuration file by the "=" sign.